# Switch from DDE to something that works, probably like libname

Tags: sas, excel-2016, dde

The new office package does not support DDE command in SAS, do you know how to make the following code work without DDE. Thanks.

```
%macro report(type=);
options mlogic noxwait noxsync;

%SYSEXEC "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\excel.exe"; 
%SYSEXEC "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\excel.exe";

data _null_;
x=sleep(10);
run;

filename Commands dde 'excel|system';
DATA _null_;
FILE commands;
PUT '[ERROR(FALSE)]';
*Put'[open("path")]';
Put '[open("path")]';
Put '[PROTECT.DOCUMENT(FALSE, FALSE, , FALSE, FALSE)]';
RUN;

/*
%LET SHEET=DISPUTE2;
%PUT &SHEET;
%LET DATA=DISPUTE2;
%PUT &DATA;
*/
%MACRO SHEET(SHEET=);
filename HEAD1 dde "EXCEL|&SHEET!R6C1:R6C1" NOTAB;
filename CRU dde "EXCEL|&SHEET!R7C1:R500C1" NOTAB;
```

Comment: `I tried something with libname` Please, always share what you've tried, and in what way it "didn't work".  Errors?  Check out [mcve] for more info.  You can always [edit] your questions to add more information.

Comment: That code is not complete. Also do not nest macro definitions inside for each other, it is just confusing for programmers. Please explain what you actually want to do.   Looks perhaps like you want to unprotect a spreadsheet?  Are you running SAS on a Windows machine?

Comment: I am running SAS on windows, and I would like to stop using DDE command because office 2016 does not support it anymore.

Comment: You have to turn DDE on within Excel 2016. It still works but you should consider changing your technology soon.

Comment: How do I turn it on?

Comment: @tazz Google is your friend.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E72988_01/ICSMV/ch06s14.html

Comment: I have tried that but still it doesn't work. I have also used to SAS plug in 7.1 and still the same result. :/

Comment: Or is there any other way than DDE?

Comment: Hard to answer if there is a way other than DDE unless you explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to open a existing template and insert data in specific rows/cells etc. thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a way to turn on DDE in Excel 2016.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3001579/an-error-occurred-when-sending-commands-to-the-program-error-in-excel

1. On the Tools menu, click Options.
2. Click the General tab.
3. Clear the Ignore other applications that use Dynamic Data Exchange
   (DDE) check box, and then click OK.

It would probably be better to re-engineer your process to not use DDE, but for help with that you would need to explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have tried that but still it doesn't work. I have also used to SAS plug in 7.1 and still the same result. :/ What I am trying to do is open excel and write on a specific template various data.

Comment: Is there an other way than DDE?